# Dynamically populating list from 2 Vue-multiselect forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I have some troubles inheriting the selected values from the country field to the campaign field.

I have 2 sub components (country and campaign) which both use Vue-multiselect.

I use `country` as props to campaign component since the listing in campaign is dependent upon the country the users select.

This is my main fields form:

```
    <Country 
        :load-data="form.country"
        v-on:country-select="countrySelected"
        v-on:country-remove="countryRemove">
    </Country>
             
    <Campaign
        :load-data="form.campaign"
        :country="countrySelected"
        v-on:campaign-select="CampaignSelected"
        v-on:campaign-remove="CampaignRemove">
    </Campaign>
```

and this is my campaign subcomponent:

```
    <multiselect 
       tag-placeholder="Add this as new campaign name"
       placeholder="Search or add a campaign name"
       v-model="value" 
       :options="options" 
       label="name"
       track-by="id"
       :multiple="true"
       :taggable="true"
       :disabled="this.disabled"
       @select="selected"
       @remove="remove">
    </multiselect>
```

Where I declare `country` as props:

```
props: 
    {
        country:''
    },
```

and method to get campaign:

```
TableFilterService.getCampaignNames()
    .then((response) => {
        this.options = response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Campaign sample data:

```
data: 
    {
        au : 
            {
               id : '1111', 
               name: 'ddddd' 
            }
    }
```

Comment: When you declare props you can declare their type: `country: String` but you're declaring it like you would data: `country: ''`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights thanks, I tried that. but its not working

Comment: For your data in `Campaign` it should be declared like this: `data() { return: { au: etc... } }`

Comment: What is your question?